# Square Root of $320$

Tags: exponentiation, square-numbers

Given, 
  $$\sqrt{5} = 2.236$$
  $$\sqrt{320} = 2^3 \times \sqrt{5} = 8 \times 2.236 = 17.888$$

This is the explanation provided in my school book. Could someone please elaborate ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are approximations, not equalities. We have $\sqrt{5}\approx 2.236,\, \sqrt{320}=2^3\cdot \sqrt{5}\approx 8\cdot 2.236=17.888$.

Comment: But how is √320 = 2^3√5

Comment: It uses the property $a,b\ge 0\,\Rightarrow\, \sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$. In this case, let $a=64=2^6,\, b=5$

Comment: $320 = 32 \times 10 = 2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times5=2^6\times5$.  So $(2^65)^{1/2}=2^35^{1/2}$.

Comment: How do you use under root symbol and superscript?

Comment: \sqrt{x}, x^{y}. Put $ around the expression so it will appear. You can also view latex code by right-clicking on it. Here is a MathJax tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses three facts: that $\sqrt{a}=a^{1/2}$ and $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ and $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$.

$320 = 32 \times 10 = 2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times5=2^6\times5$.  So $(2^65)^{1/2}=2^35^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$320=64\cdot 5=2^6\cdot 5$ Then $\sqrt{320}=\sqrt{2^6\cdot 5}=\sqrt{2^6}\cdot \sqrt{5}=2^3\cdot \sqrt{5}$